# Comparing distances between old and new Esri geocode locator points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, distance, geocoding

I need to check the accuracy of the locators between Esri's Streetmap 14_2 and Streetmap 15_1. The two layers need one to one distances measured between points that have the same attributes i.e. same address, city, state, and zip. The tables are exactly the same essentially with the exception of X and Y coordinates. Would the point distance tool be the best option? A colleague suggested the point distance tool and selecting the points individually. With 150 million records, that seems like it would take a while. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge your old and new feature classes into one, then, using the Points to Line tool, input your merged table, and use the common field as the "line field"

Comment: What an insightful answer! Thank you so much, sir!

Comment: my pleasure, good luck with your task!

Comment: I can now move forward thanks to your great knowledge and true wisdom. You must be truly skilled and above all others in the GIS field.